# Mariadb not starting on amazon linux

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mariadb

I am new to `aws` server configuration. I have setup an `nginx` web server with `mariadb` database server for my `php/laravel` web application. My database server was running good for the last few days hence my website was running without any error. But yesterday the database server has been stopped working automatically. I tried to start `mariadb` but it is not starting.

I noticed that the database server (mariadb) stops working after a few days of my fresh server installation. I suspect it could be a memory problem but I cannot find out the problem.

I have setup the the server following the aws documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-lamp-amazon-linux-2.html

Can anyone give some ideas about the problem?

Comment: Check your logs.

Comment: Where is the log file? I cannot find mysql folder inside log folder but there is a mariadb folder.Here is the screenshot https://prnt.sc/wvhnb2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my own problem. Following Stanley's answer, I opened the log file: /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log.
There I found line

```
mariadb Cannot allocate memory
```

That means, the RAM size of my server was not enough to run all the applications. That's why mariadb server was getting stopped. There are two solution:

1. Increasing the RAM size
2. Creating a swap space

I choose the second option and followed amazon's documentation: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-memory-swap-file/

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check the error logs. The error log contains a record of critical errors that occurred during the server's operation, table corruption, start and stop information.

```
On Linux, the default location is /var/log/mysql/
```

You will find the actual reason for what is the problem of the MariaDB server once you check the error log.

Comment: I cannot find mysql folder inside log folder but there is a mariadb folder.Here is the screenshot https://prnt.sc/wvhnb2

Comment: Ok then open mariadb file and check it.